# Laravel 5.2 php artisan migrate:rollback error

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

I use Laravel 5.2 and I created database tables by running

```
php artisan make:migration create_categories_table --create=categories
```

and

```
php artisan make:migration create_posts_table --create=posts
```

and then I run `php artisan migrate`, and tables are created in database. But after I made some changes in migration file "create_posts_table.php" and run

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

I got an error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>     Class 'CreatePostsTable' not found
>   PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CreatePostsTable' not found in E:\programfiles\xampp\htdocs\deneme\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator.php on line 336

my create_posts_table.php is [image]

I tried `composer update`, `composer dump-autoload` but that hasn't fixed the problem.

Answer (score 26):

I was getting the same problem. May this helps somebody: run `composer dump-autoload` before running `migrate:rollback`.

Answer (score 9):

Before you run a migration, you should run the following commands to make sure cache has been cleared:

- `php artisan clear-compiled`
- `php artisan optimize`

This will make sure your new migration class has been registered correctly.